# Python: Add four lists to a dictionary that already has keys, all lists/dict have same length of values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures, append

I have 5 lists:

```
periods = []
interface_sum = []
intraslab_sum = []
crustal_sum = []
total_sums = []
```

I want to make the periods list as the key, then have the rest of those lists appended onto the periods key. Here is what the data looks like:

[image]

So from this pic, I want the top list that says like 0.001, 0.1, 0.2, etc to be the keys, then I want the four lists below that to be appended to their respective key. So like it would be:

```
data = {'0.001':[16.36,35.45,48.15,99.96], '0.1':[11.10,43.40,45.49,99.99], etc}
```

Any ideas on how to get this done? Thanks.

Comment: Why is the data posted as a pic and not as python?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)...[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ... 
[You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest case would be to use `zip` twice; once for the values and again for key-value pairs and use the dict constructor:

```
out = dict(zip(periods, zip(interface_sum, intraslab_sum, crustal_sum, total_sums)))
```

For example, if:

```
periods = [1,2,3]
interface_sum = [4,5,6]
intraslab_sum = [7,8,9]
crustal_sum = [10,11,12]
total_sums = [13,14,15]
```

Then output:

```
{1: (4, 7, 10, 13), 2: (5, 8, 11, 14), 3: (6, 9, 12, 15)}
```

As you can see it creates tuples as values. If you want them as lists, you can do so by mapping them:

```
out = dict(zip(periods, map(list, zip(interface_sum, intraslab_sum, crustal_sum, total_sums))))
```

or use a dict comprehension:

```
out = {k: list(v) for k,v in zip(periods, zip(interface_sum, intraslab_sum, crustal_sum, total_sums))}
```